# Why does Format File cause error during SQL Server Bulk Insert?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert a CSV file into SQL Server 2017 using an XML Format File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="Col_0" xsi:type="CharTerm" MAX_LENGTH="100" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_1" xsi:type="CharTerm" MAX_LENGTH="100" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_2" xsi:type="CharTerm" MAX_LENGTH="3" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_3" xsi:type="CharFixed" Length="19" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_4" xsi:type="CharFixed" Length="19" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_5" xsi:type="CharFixed" Length="53" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_6" xsi:type="CharFixed" Length="10" TERMINATOR=","/>
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_0" NAME="NAME" xsi:type="SQLVARCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_1" NAME="MATCHNAME" xsi:type="SQLVARCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_2" NAME="CHROMOSOME" xsi:type="SQLVARCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_3" NAME="START_LOCATION" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_4" NAME="END_LOCATION" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_5" NAME="CENTIMORGANS" xsi:type="SQLFLT4"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_6" NAME="MATCHING_SNPS" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

When I execute this, I get this error message:

> Error during Execute
>    37000(4855)[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Line 2 in format file "c:\temp\FormatFile.xml": unexpected element "BCPFORMAT".

I'm at a loss to understand why the BCPFORMAT element is not recognized. The XML is properly formatted according to Altova XMYSpy.

The code to perform the upload is:

```
bulk insert FF_ChromBrwResults_20190124 from 'c:\temp\temp.csv'
 with (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',FIRSTROW =1,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
,KEEPIDENTITY,CODEPAGE ='OEM',KEEPNULLS, FORMATFILE = 'c:\temp\FormatFile.xml' )
```

The CSV has many rows in this format, ending with a linefeed:

> Name1,Name2, 1,48745397,54260005,2.84,1000

I've tried executing this from .NET code and in AQT where the ODBC connection is working; both methods produced the same error.

Answer (score 13):

This error occurs because the url for xmlns contains HTTPS correct is HTTP.

INCORRECT = `<BCPFORMAT xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

CORRECT = `<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

Your XML file also need one modification transform all CharFixed to CharTerm once the delimiter of CharFixed is not comma but length property.

Change too all type SQLVARCHAR to SQLVARYCHAR

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="Col_0" xsi:type="CharTerm" MAX_LENGTH="100" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_1" xsi:type="CharTerm" MAX_LENGTH="100" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_2" xsi:type="CharTerm" MAX_LENGTH="3" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
        <FIELD ID="Col_6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_0" NAME="NAME" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_1" NAME="MATCHNAME" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_2" NAME="CHROMOSOME" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_3" NAME="START_LOCATION" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_4" NAME="END_LOCATION" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_5" NAME="CENTIMORGANS" xsi:type="SQLFLT4"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="Col_6" NAME="MATCHING_SNPS" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: Thank you. I applied these corrections. But, as mentioned in my comment above, I'm still getting an error. This may be a connection problem (ODBC). But that is pecular as other queries run

Comment: OK. There may have been several issues that, when addressed, resolved this:
1) those both Davd & Fernando mention; 2) I had not installed the bcp utility and 3) my command needed to specify the database and use dbo.  With these changes, things are working ... many thanks for the help!

Comment: I have been struggling with this for a few hours, and there are several issues, but all of MS Docs show to use the 'https" and not one mention of 'http".  Thank you, this helped greatly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this solved my problem :) Seems like there are lots templates to be found that don't work

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, as I find format files an enduring mystery, but try letting BCP generate the format file, eg:

```
bcp tempdb.dbo.FF_ChromBrwResults_20190124 format nul -c -x -t "," -f formatfile_gen.xml  -T -S localhost
```

which for this table

```
create table FF_ChromBrwResults_20190124
(
  NAME varchar(100),
  MATCHNAME varchar(100),
  CHROMOSOME varchar(30),
  START_LOCATION bigint,
  END_LOCATION bigint,
  CENTIMORGANS real,
  MATCHING_SNPS smallint
)
```

outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="21"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="21"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="30"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="7"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="NAME" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="MATCHNAME" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="CHROMOSOME" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="START_LOCATION" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="END_LOCATION" xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="CENTIMORGANS" xsi:type="SQLFLT4"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="MATCHING_SNPS" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still getting the same error with a slight variation:

Error during Execute
 37000(102)[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '.'.
37000(8180)[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.

I wonder if bcp requires a different ODBC than queries?